# Mounting Directories with bind & different permissions

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, mount, bind, fstab

I’m running Ubuntu 13.04 & trying to mount a folder using [`bind`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind) in `/etc/fstab`. Shown below is one of many similar entries;

```
/media/Storage1/test   /media/Storage1/WebDAV/Alex     none    bind,uid=www-data,gid=alex    0       0
```

The directory is mounted upon startup and if I navigate to either of these directories the files are matched. The issue I have is that the permissions are not changed!!!

In the above example (/media/Storage1)

- /test is owned by root:root
- /WebDAV/Alex is owned by www-data:alex

However when mounted, `/media/Storage1/WebDAV/Alex` is now root:root

The same is the case for all my directories mounted in this way (root is not the only owner of original directory, additionally I have tried `uid=33,gid=1000`)

Am I using `bind` incorrectly? Am I doing something hideously wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The bind option is not a real filesystem and does not support the uid and gid parameters. Specify the user or owner option to get the desired effect.

```
$ ll /tmp/moo/ -d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 40 Jul 24 01:07 /tmp/moo/

$ mount /tmp/moo

$ ll /tmp/moo/ -d
drwxr-xr-x 42 jaroslav jaroslav 4096 Jul 24 01:05 /tmp/moo/

$ grep bind,user /etc/fstab
/home/jaroslav/tmp /tmp/moo none bind,user      0 0
```

Comment: Have a look at this reply: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=95011#p474838