# How to make directory accessible to others using --bind option

Tags: linux, permissions, mount

Let's say I have access to directory on some filesystem - `/media/vc1/` mounted and owned by `user1`. I want to give access to `user2` (uid == 1001) to some directory in `/media/vc1/` (without making copy of files). Ideally, I would like to create directory `/home/user2/mnt` which would contain contents of `/media/vc1/` . I have tried to run following command as `root`:

```
mount --bind -o uid=1001 /media/vc1/ /home/user2/mnt/
```

It does not work, here is stat of `mnt` directory:

```
Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: ( 1000/   user1)   Gid: ( 1000/   user1)
```

and access is denied to `user2`.

To be clear, I'm not able to remount `/media/vc1` as different user.

According to [this](https://superuser.com/a/623383/224348) answer, you can't use `uid` and `gid` options with `--bind`. I'm not sure how correct command would look like (I don't want to make this permanent using `fstab`.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `--bind` option does one thing only: It translates paths, much like a symlink does. It does not act as a standalone filesystem and does not override any access checks.

To alter UIDs, use an actual overlay filesystem such as [bindfs](https://bindfs.org/).